# What does the assert_template mean in Micheal Harl's Ruby on Rails listing 8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

In Micheal Harl's Ruby on Rails tutorial, chapter 6, things get a bit confusing to me about the test codes in listing 8.7 below:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test 'login with invalid information' do
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end
end
```

The code above is to catch an unwanted flash error message persistence issue, but I'm not so sure where the `assert_template` came from.

Can someone explan the code above?

Comment: Have you checked the docs? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TemplateAssertions.html#method-i-assert_template

Answer (score 0):

From the [Rails API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TemplateAssertions.html#method-i-assert_template):

> Asserts that the request was rendered with the appropriate template file or partials.

For documentation on each of the lines above, I really advice you to google each one alone (something like "assert_template rails" on Google will do the job).